# Typescript Declare Class Type

Tags: typescript

In Javascript I have:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
new SequelizeStore({
    db: sequelize
});
```

I set these types:

```
function ConnectSessionSequelize(store: expressSession.IBaseStore): expressSession.IBaseStore;
```

This fails because expressSession.IBaseStore refers to an instance type, not a class type. Is there a way to specify class types, similar to Java: `Class<expressSession.IBaseStore>`?

Currently I'm using `function CoSeSe(store: Function): Function`, but this has major type leakage!

Comment: it sounds like Store should inherit or extend IBaseStore. does it?

Comment: It implements it: ```export class Store implements IBaseStore```.

Comment: hm.. is there a specific error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `typeof SomeClass` will give you the type of the constructor function `SomeClass` (e.g. the type of `x` if you wrote `let x = SomeClass`) rather than the instance side (e.g. the type of `y` if you wrote `let y = new SomeClass()`).

Comment: You are truly amazing: ```function CoSeSe(store: typeof expressionSession.Store): typeof expressionSession.Store```.